# When trying to login to phpMyAdmin username always appended with "@[current hostname]"

Tags: phpmyadmin

No matter what my configuration options in config.inc.php are, I cannot login to MariaDB on another server since username is always appended automatically wilth "@" and "host1" (current hostname).

Let's say my phpMyAdmin is running on host1 and MariaDB on host2. I open phpMyAdmin in the browser on host1 and try to login with root and its correct password, however I get an error such as:

**#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'host1' (using password: YES)**

Of course, it cannot login with root@host1 since database is on host2!

If I try to specify username as root@host2, I get:

**#1045 - Access denied for user 'root@host2'@'host1' (using password: YES)**

Answer (score 1):

It's another day and everything is clear now.

First of all, I cannot force phpMyAdmin not to add "@" and current hostname to the username entered or specified (which I kind of knew from the beginning).

Second, all users in MariaDB (or MySQL) database are of format "user@hostname".

So, the only way to login from host1 to the database on host2, there must be a user in the database with host host2. This means in the mysql.user table there must be an entry, in this case, root@host2, or with the column user having value root and host having value of "%", which is a wild card meaning any host.